# How to set PATH for all applications on a per-user basis in macOS?

Tags: macos, authentication, path, environment-variables

I'm looking for a way to set the `PATH` environment variable for **all** applications that **I** (and only I) run under macOS (version 14 / Sonoma at the time of writing.)  That sounds like it *ought* to be straightforward, but it seems not to be, and I haven't found any current, working instructions on how to do it.

To be clear, here are three things that I **do** know how to do, that there are (some) decent instructions out there for, and that are **not** what I'm asking about now:

1. Set the environment variables for a shell (e.g. zsh, bash, etc) and by extension applications that are launched *from* that shell.  All the normal UNIX techniques and configuration files work fine for this.  If I set a variable in my `~/.zshrc` and then start any app I want (GUI or not) from within zsh, it works as expected.
2. Set an environment variable which is **not** `PATH` for apps *not* launched from a shell.  There are several ways of doing that using `launchctl setenv`, and they're dirty and hackish, but they work.  I've written up one way of doing that at [Add system-wide environment-variables in MacOS Ventura](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/12ryky5/comment/k3qcjf3/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3).  However, macOS appears to have special-case handling for `PATH` that's different from other environment variables.
3. Change the `PATH` variable for **all** users:  I can add entries to `/etc/paths` or `/etc/paths.d/` but then those affect everybody, which is actively unhelpful on a multi-user system, especially since I want to include some directories that other users can't even access.

So, those out of the way, does anyone know of a command, configuration file, settings option, magic incantation, etc. that will let me set the `PATH` variable given to any process I launch, no matter how I launch it (e.g as a login item, from Finder, from the dock, whatever) that doesn't involve making a system-wide change and messing up other users?

Note: I know this question straddles the lines between being user problem, a sysadmin problem, and a programmer problem.  I'm posting it here because (a) I originally posted it on the AskDifferent site and nobody had an answer, and (b) anything resembling a *solution* seems to involve actual programming.

Comment: `any process I launch`. Can you give a couple of examples of those processes and what/how you want to give PATH to them ? `anything resembling a solution seems to involve actual programming`. I think you `have` to do some shell programming.

Comment: @Philippe sure: the main ones are editors of one sort or another that invoke other tools (which they need to be able to find in PATH).  For example, programming editors often launch compilers, interpreters, linters, etc., and some other tools try to use LaTeX, graphviz, and ispell.   Any macOS program, however launched (e.g. from _finder_) gets _a_ value of PATH, but it comes from system-wide settings, not per-user ones.

(Also, I'm not *against* programming, that part was justifying why the Q belongs on StackOverflow.)